# Semantic UI Sidebar module settings

Tags: semantic-ui

Is there a way to override module settings at compile time rather than at run time like this:

```
$('.sideMenu').sidebar('setting', { dimPage: false });
```

Comment: I don't understand - what do you mean by "compile time"? What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply deliver setting as JSON to the function in Semantic UI 2.3:

```
$(selector)
  .modules({
    settingName: val
  });
```